# Lower sort renamed column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Why this: `SELECT (users.email) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY lower(renamed_column) DESC` doesn't work?
(error column renamed_column doesn't exist)

I'm not interessted by `SELECT lower(users.email) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY renamed_column DESC` because I want original value sorted by lowered value.

PS: This is an example, in fact, 'users.email' is replaced by a sub-request. But the problem exists with simple field or sub-request. I don't understand why the ORDER BY lower() with a renamed column fails.

Comment: Unrelated, but: don't add useless parentheses. It's better to use `users.email` instead of `(users.email)`. Putting columns between parentheses will not always do what you think it does (e.g. `(col1, col2)`  is something different than `col1, col2` in Postgres!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `renamed_column` you give is only used for results and can be used only in limited fashion in other parts. [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) states about `ORDER BY` clause:

> Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values.

So it seems it's ok to do `ORDER BY renamed_column DESC` since it is an *output column*, but if it is an "arbitrary expression", it must use *input column values*.

So the only way to do this is

```
SELECT (users.email) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY lower(users.email) DESC
```

Comment: but this: `SELECT (users.email) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY renamed_column DESC` works. It's possible to use alias in order clause, but not execute function on it?

Comment: @barbacan Actually, you are right. Didn't test well enough, it does work on ordering...

Comment: @barbacan Found the part of documentation that talks about this

Comment: Thanks for the distinction output column / input column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (users.email) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY lower((users.email)) DESC
```

Comment: works perfectly but, with sub-request, by example :
`SELECT (SELECT('TEST')::text) AS renamed_column FROM users ORDER BY lower((SELECT('TEST')::text)) DESC`
two same sub-requests are launched...